# How to add districts to woocommere delivery area?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can add a city to the shipping area and set shipping rates for that city. However, when I wanted to calculate the shipping cost by county, I had not thought of a solution. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In WooCommerce -> Settings -> General make sure you are selling to multiple countries. Then in -> Shipping set 'Zones' for each Country with your shipping options.